# Не работают не сами ссылки, ни правила htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

Привет и сразу спасибо всем ответившим.

Есть 2 хостинга и 1 сайт. На 1-м хостинге ссылки сайта работают в 2-x вариантах, включая правила htaccess. На 2-м не работают совсем хотя при клике адрес в строке браузера меняется вот не работающий пример _xttp://autotur38.ru/ а вот работающий _xttp://portbaikal.ru/ подскажите в какую сторону копать?

правила htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+).html$ /index.php?a=$1&url=$2

Comment: Эм... на обоих сайтах ссылки работают. или там есть скрытый смысл?

Answer (score 1):

Ну я думаю что нужно в первую очередь глянуть на настройку виртуальных хостов и сравнить их.

Попробуйте добавить следующее в настройку виртуалХост:

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```